# jinja2 if else in select tag

Tags: jinja2, html-select

```
        <select class="form-control" id="types" name="types" combojs="types">
            {% for t in tdata %}
            <option value="{{ t[0] }}" {% if t[0] == t1is %} selected {% endif %}>
                {{ t[0] }}
            </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

I use python flask render_template to pass tdata as list, and t1is as selected.
This works for a drop down combobox, with the t1is being the selected option displayed,
but can I also set a default if not selected with t1is. I tried to put {% else t[0] == "None" %} after selected, but I don't have any idea if it is right syntax. And of course it does not work. The first item is displayed if nothing selected. Do I need to make the default item first in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only determine that there is no match after the `for` loop is finished, by which time it's already too late to add the `selected` attribute to the desired default option.

To work around it you can use another loop beforehand to decide which option should be selected:

```
{% set ns = namespace(selected="None") %}
{% for t in tdata if t[0] == t1is %}
    {% set ns.selected = t1is %}
{% endfor %}
<select class="form-control" id="types" name="types" combojs="types">
    {% for t in tdata %}
    <option value="{{ t[0] }}" {% if t[0] == ns.selected %} selected {% endif %}>
        {{ t[0] }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```